# Rescue background job fails to load config values from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-kms

We have application is written  using Ruby on Rails Language `(4.2x)`

Hosted on AWS in docker containers – 3 docker contains are

- Web application container
- Background job resque container
- Resque-scheduler container

We are using AWS Secrets Manager is where we store connection data for external API calls.

We have a background job running with code for an external API call. 
 
When code in the web application container gets called by the background job we are experiencing issues with

`Rails.application.config_for(:external_api_service)` returning empty values hence failing the api call.

Exact same code works fine when it is getting called within the web application itself.

```
module ExternaAPI
  class Client

    class_attribute :config
    self.config = Rails.application.config_for(:external_api_service)

  end
end
```

external_api_service . yml file

```
staging: &live_settings

  :name: <%= ENV["API_USERNAME"] %>
  :password: <%= ENV["API_PASSWORD"] %>
  :subdomain: <%= ENV["API_SUBDOMAIN"] %>
```

anyone ever had similar issues ?

Comment: How you can store connection details in KMS? The service is not used for storing anything except your private encryption keys.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Secrets Manager

Comment: Does the `Background job resque container` has permissions to access the key? Maybe permissions are only set for the web app container, thus explaining why it works only there?

Comment: Within the Background job I can access those config data fine. Rails.application.config_for(:external_api_service) 
Only when web application container code gets called through background job it is blank